# How to produce a random food in a snake game on c?

Tags: c

i am trying to create a snake game using C.

and i am trying to find an efficient algorithm to produce a random food position.

here is my current algorithm for the generateFood() function:

1. generate a random food coordinate
2. while coordinate is on a snake head || body:
3. generate new random food coordinate

this algorithm would work for the first half of the game, but when the snake started to increase in size.
getting a coordinate randomly to finally get a free spot will be taking a much longer time complexity and extremely inconsistent.

i'm thinking to put all the empty coordinates into a linked list
and move random steps to get to a coordinate. and it would update accordingly to the snake coordinates, so that it can generate a random food by the first run.

but i find this method unnecessarily complicated and 
could took up a lot of memory & time.

is there any other ways that i can do this much more efficiently on C?
thx

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: It can be similar to a Fisher-Yates shuffle: put all the possible locations in an array, pick one at random, replace it with the topmost element in the array, and reduce the maximum value of the next random index by 1.

Comment: Do you have a performance issue or is this premature optimization?

Comment: What I tend to do in similar situations is a) pick a random position; b) while (badchoice) advance by one. For example: pick a random number between 10 and 99 that is prime -- a) random yields 98; b) 98 --> 99 --> 10 --> 11 stop

Answer (score 2):

I think you need 2 arrays.

One contains the positions of all the free pixels, and the other, the free pixel map would contain location of each pixel in the free pixels array, if it is free.

Whenever you *occupy a new pixel* you remove it from the free pixels array. If it was the last item, you just *decrease the counter* for free pixels. If it is not the last pixel of the free pixels array, you'll "swap" it with the last pixel of the free array first.

Since both the free pixel array and the map of free pixels are linked to each other, occupying a new pixel only takes O(1) updates to the structures; same applies for when a pixel is freed again.

Now, *choosing* a free pixel at random for food is really easy, it is an O(1) operation - just choose a number from `0` through `n_free_pixels - 1` and choose the `ith` pixel from the free pixel array.

For this approach you'll need about 4-8 bytes extra memory per pixel; if say 320x200 is enough, then 4 bytes per pixel for 256k (both arrays will have unsigned shorts). BUT if you place the food in a *grid* and consider a grid position unusable if the snake occupies any part of it, then you can get away with much less.

---

Consider a 2x2 map for simplicity. In the beginning all pixels free, so the contents of the maps would be

```
Free pixel map        Free pixel list
+-----+-----+
|0    |1    |         | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 
|  0  |  1  |
|     |     |
+-----+-----+         n_free = 4
|2    |3    |
|  2  |  3  |
|     |     |
+-----+-----+
```

Then you want to choose one pixel to occupy, and choose a number between 0 and n_free - 1. In this case 1. Now you take the pixel position from the free pixel list at index 1 (which is also 1)...

```
Free pixel map        Free pixel list
+-----+-----+
|0    |1    |         | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 
|  0  |  1  |               ^
|     |     |
+-----+-----+         n_free = 4
|2    |3    |
|  2  |  3  |
|     |     |
+-----+-----+
```

We mark that pixel as reserved in the free pixel map

```
Free pixel map        Free pixel list
+-----+-----+
|0    |1    |         | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 
|  0  |  #  |               
|     |     |
+-----+-----+         n_free = 4
|2    |3    |
|  2  |  3  |
|     |     |
+-----+-----+
```

Since the position in free list wasn't the last, we'll swap the 
last element (pixel 3) into that position, and update the free map to point to that index, and finally decrease `n_free` by one:

```
Free pixel map        Free pixel list
+-----+-----+
|0    |1    |         | 0 | 3 | 2 
|  0  |  #  |               ^
|     |     |
+-----+-----+         n_free = 3
|2    |3    |
|  2  |  1  |
|     |  ^  |
+-----+-----+
```

---

If pixel `1` is subsequently *released*, we can add it at the position `n_free` of the free list, and modify the map to point to that element and finally increase `n_free`; the new state would be

```
Free pixel map        Free pixel list
+-----+-----+
|0    |1    |         | 0 | 3 | 2 | 1
|  0  |  3  |                       ^
|     |     |
+-----+-----+         n_free = 4
|2    |3    |
|  2  |  1  |
|     |     |
+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

One way that might solve the problem is this:

```
gridSize = getTotalNumberOfCells()
snakeSize = getSnakeSize()
cellsLeft = gridSize-snakeSize
randomCell = random(cellsLeft)

cell = 0
do
    while occupiedBySnake(cell)
        cell++
while randomCell-- > 0
```

This method goes through the cell one by one until it has gone through `randomCell` number of cells, NOT counting the cells occupied by the snake.

Maybe not the best algorithm for this, but at least the time it will take to run is predictable. It will for sure be slower than your present algorithm when the snake is small, but it's possible that it would be able to handle it fast enough. Of course this can largely depend on the number of cells.

If you have a grid of 300x300 (a VERY large snake game) you would have almost 100000 cells. Checking if a cell is occupied should be able to do in maximum 200ns. I assume a cache miss, which will rarely be the case. 200ns * 100000 = 0.02s. That's enough for 50fps.

Note that I was very pessimistic. 200ns is pretty long. Between 50 and 100 is more typical when you access the memory. But in practice, a grid of 100000 cells will always be in L2 cache, which has a typical access time of 20ns. If you reduce the size to 200x200, then chances are that the whole grid fits in the L1 cache, which has an access time of around 1ns. So for a 200x200 grid, this method could produce 25000fps. Do you need more or is that enough? ;)

But I can smell premature optimization in your question. Does it run fast enough? If yes, why bother?

> I find this method unnecessarily complicated and could took up a lot of memory & time.

Well, if you don't need it then it for sure is overly complicated. But your concern of memory usage is uncalled for. Can you really imagine running your game on a computer where the memory usage would be an issue when you're coding this in C? Especially since the size of that extra list would grow linearly with the grid size. Unless you're planning on running this game on a computer from the early 70:s, I can assure you that it will not be an issue.

Comment: maybe you're right since i am still optimizing the algorithms before testing  it. i may be too concerned for the speed of the program since i am working with a 256 x 256 map. but my computer can as well handle big memory usage, although my concern is with the consistency of getting the free spots randomly, which could heavily affect the speed of the program, especially if there is just 1 free spot on a 256 x 256 map. thx again for your feedback, im going to try your algorithm.

Comment: There is a HUGE difference between "could affect" and "affects". The latter one is a good argument for optimization. The first is not.

Answer (score 0):

While picking randomly and then incrementing until you found an empty spot is faster, the probability that the food will be next to the snake will increase as the snake grows.  Thus making the game harder as time goes on, since food right next to the snake is harder to eat than food that is away from the snake.  So it's a trade off between computing a truly random cell (slower but most random) and pseudo-random (faster but skewed).

One way to minimize (or make constant) the compute time is to keep track of the empty spots as the snake moves (removing from tail and adding from head) in an array, and pick a random an index for the food.